# Background-image without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, background, height, background-image

so I have a background image inside my header, but when I make the height of the header 100% then a scroll-bar appears and I don't want it there

```
<header>
    <div class="header-text">Velkommen til Rakhman Trafikkskole</div>
</header>



html,body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
} 

header {
  background-image: url("../bilder/Rakhman\ Trafikkskole\ header\ image.jpeg");
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.85;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
```

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, so I am sorry if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` in the CSS of header.

Refer to W3schools here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow: hidden;` in your css.